# How to make children float inside side-by-side elements, in a fixed with container?

Tags: css

I have the situation:

**html:**

```
<div class="container0">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

**css:**

```
.container0 {
  width:600px; /*needed*/
}

.item {
  border: solid;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: auto; /*needed, should be width of the contents*/
}

.subitens {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
.child {
    background: blue;
    border: solid;
    width: 100px; /*needed*/
    height: 100px; /*needed*/
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/gx7kL330/6/

And I would like the `.item` elements to be side by side, while the `.child` elements would float to fit in the space (600px). Any idea?

Comment: @AlexChar the `.item` elements should be side by side, the second on the right, not bottom. The `.child` elements can float to fit the 600px fixed conteiner width.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

```css
.container0 {
  width:600px; /*needed*/
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
  background: yellow;
}

.subitens {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container0">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Here is my first sample, non `flex`, which actually works as good because the `child` elements have a fixed `width`

```css
.container0 {
  width:600px; /*needed*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.item {
  border: solid;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.subitens {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  border: solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container0">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="subitens">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Great! But my `.item` cannot have `width: 50%;`, as there will be a undefined number of itens... The `.childen` elements should float for the itens to fit the 600px width of the parent.

Comment: @TomBrito For that you need `flex` (or `display: table`). Updated my answer.